# Не сохраняется изображение

Tags: android

Выбираю изображение из галереи, но оно не сохраняется ни в памяти телефона на на флешке. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnItemClickListener, MyDialogFragment.OnButtonClick {

    private ImageView imgView;
    static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Выбрать"), GALLERY_REQUEST);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            switch(requestCode) {
                case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        try {
                            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                          } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        createDirectoryAndSaveFile(bitmap, "tttt", "uuuuu");
                    }
            }

    }

    private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName, String dirName) {

        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + dirName);

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + dirName);
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + dirName), fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) неправильно формируете пути - между папками должны быть слеши (`/`); 2) разрешение на запись файлов получено?

Comment: Разрешение добавил в манифест. А если неправильно указан путь не должно выдавать ошибку? У меня не выдает ошибок

Comment: В логах хорошо смотрели? Поскольку критичные места обработаны в `try-catch`, `e.printStackTrace();` выводит ошибку в `LogCat` "по-тихому".

Comment: Вот что выдало в логах java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0uuuuu/tttt.jpg (No such file or directory)... А как правильно путь указать?

Comment: `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), dirName);` или `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + dirName);`

Comment: Сделал как вы указали все равно пишет java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/uuuuu/tttt.jpg (No such file or directory). В картинка в ImageView добавляется. В Манифесте <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Мало добавить в манифест разрешение, надо его еще запросить, а потом каждый раз проверять, есть ли оно.

Comment: Написал так   int permissionStatus = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                        if (permissionStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            createDirectoryAndSaveFile(bitmap, "tttt.jpg", "uuuuu");
                        }  экспешн не показывается теперь, но и файл не сохраняется

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо.